# How to acess variable from subclass that is in main class?

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class A:
    x = 'variable'
    class B:
        #how to access variable X from class A
```

I have just started learning OOP and trying to figure out how to use it on practice.

Comment: Why are you defining one class inside another?

Comment: Can't I do so ?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, but I can't think why you would ever want to do so. If you're trying to learn inheritance, this is not how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It's not possible (or if it is, it's not easy) because as long as the block started by `class A:` hasn't finished you cannot access `A`.

However you can define it as property:

```
class A:
    x = 'variable'
    class B:
        @property
        def x(self):
            return A.x
```

The code inside methods and properties is executed when they are called so the call happens after `class A` is defined. So you can use it:

```
>>> A.B().x
'variable'
```

However I strongly advise you to **not** use nested classes if you "just started learning OOP". Try to focus on some real OOP topics like [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).